# How to apply the same logic to multiple entity objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have about 20 different report tables in my Entity Data Model that all have a few common fields (like start_date and end_date). When my reporting application pulls data for a given report, the first thing I do is filter the table for today's date. This means I have code blocks similar to this throughout my code (VB):

```
Dim data = 
    From r in _context.Rpt1 
    Where 
        r.start_date <= Now And 
        r.end_date >= Now
```

It seems like there should be a way to put this logic into a function that will let me filter any table, but I can't figure out how to structure it. I could do this:

```
Public Function FilterByDate(data As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable
    Return From d In data Where d.start_date <= Now And d.end_date >= Now
End Function
```

but since the return value is a generic IEnumerable I lose all the advantages of early binding on the specific report columns.

Is there a way to create a single generic function that can apply some logic to different objects and return that specific object instead of a generic one? Alternatively, is there a way to cast the return value back to the specific entity object type? Is there another way to attack this type of problem? Just looking for ideas or different ways of looking at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that the generated entities are partial classes by having any (or all, if they fit the bill) implement an interface `IFoo` that exposes the "common" properties like `start_date` and `end_date`.

You can then write a generic filtering method (code in C#, sorry):

```
public IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : IFoo
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    return queryable.Where(q => q.start_date <= now && q.end_date >= now);
}
```

This will accept any meaningful type of queryable thanks to the generic parameter type constraint, but still allow you to return the exact same type as passed in thanks to generic argument type deduction.